# How can I add only one cell from every excel file to new excel file?

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

location = 'C:\\Users\\rober\\Desktop\\zgony2\\*.xlsx'
excel_files = glob.glob(location)

df1 = pd.DataFrame()

for excel_file in excel_files:
    df2 = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
    df1 = pd.concat([df2.iloc[1, 1], df1.iloc[1, 1]])

df1.to_excel("C:\\Users\\rober\\Desktop\\zgony2\\asdf.xlsx", index=False)
```

I have 365 excel files and I need to take 1 same cell from every excel file and put them all in new. the problem is my code takes all the data. I tried to make it by adding `iloc` to `df2` and df 1 in for loop with column name and number of cell in that column but it gives me an error. how can I do this?

**Error:**

```
C:\PythonProjekty\excel\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/PythonProjekty/excel/laczenie plikow excela tylko 1 wartosc z kazdego.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonProjekty\excel\laczenie plikow excela tylko 1 wartosc z kazdego.py", line 11, in <module>
    df1 = pd.concat([df2.iloc[1, 1], df1.iloc[1, 1]])
  File "C:\PythonProjekty\excel\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 960, in __getitem__
    return self.obj._get_value(*key, takeable=self._takeable)
  File "C:\PythonProjekty\excel\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3613, in _get_value
    series = self._ixs(col, axis=1)
  File "C:\PythonProjekty\excel\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3440, in _ixs
    label = self.columns[i]
  File "C:\PythonProjekty\excel\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 5039, in __getitem__
    return getitem(key)
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**2 Error:**

```
C:\PythonProjekty\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:\PythonProjekty\asd.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PythonProjekty\asd.py", line 13, in <module>
    temp = pd.read_csv(excel_file)
  File "C:\PythonProjekty\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\PythonProjekty\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 680, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\PythonProjekty\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 575, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\PythonProjekty\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 933, in __init__
    self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
  File "C:\PythonProjekty\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1231, in _make_engine
    return mapping[engine](f, **self.options)
  File "C:\PythonProjekty\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 75, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 544, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 633, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 847, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1952, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 366: invalid start byte

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `i tried to make it by adding iloc to df2` where is that in your code? `it gives me error` what error?

Comment: code in first post is edited and i also add the error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are accessing an empty `df1` with `iloc`. Also, `iloc` will return a value only, so you won't be able to concat that. Since the number of values is small, you can iterate over your dataframes, append these values to the list, and create a new dataframe instead:

```py
values = []

for excel_file in excel_files:
    temp = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
    values.append(temp.iloc[1, 1])

df = pd.DataFrame({'values': values})
df.to_excel('path/here', index=False)
```

Comment: thanks bro. it works. but in my folder are csv files and when i changed pd.read_excel to pd.read_csv and df.to_excel to df.to_csv it give me error. i added it in my first post